# Collision of colnames in PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I have recently discovered PerformanceAnalytics and find it very useful for my research. However, I've spotted a strange behaviour. I'm trying to extend `InformationRatio()` to accept zero benchmark return:

```
InformationRatio <- function(Ra, Rb=NULL, scale=NA) {
  if (is.null(Rb)) {
    Rb <- Ra[, 1, FALSE]
    Rb[] <- 0
  }
  PerformanceAnalytics::InformationRatio(Ra, Rb, scale)
}

InformationRatio(managers[, 1:6])
```

returns

```
                        HAM1     HAM2    HAM3      HAM4      HAM5    HAM6
Information Ratio: HAM1  Inf 1.373211 1.19553 0.6592017 0.2355561 1.66417
```

Inf is not what I'd expect. Turns out (after browsing the source), that the origin of this is contained in `Return.excess()`:

```
    coln.Rf = colnames(Rf)
    Rft = cbind(R, Rf)
    Rft = na.locf(Rft[, make.names(coln.Rf)])
    Rf = Rft[which(index(R) %in% index(Rft))]
```

If there's a collision in colnames between asset returns (Ra==R) and benchmark returns (Rb==Rf), then Rf is assigned to R, which eventually leads to division by zero.

Here's a workaround:

```
InformationRatio <- function(Ra, Rb=NULL, scale=NA) {
  if (is.null(Rb)) {
    Rb <- Ra[, 1, FALSE]
    Rb[] <- 0
    colnames(Rb) <- "zero"
  }
  PerformanceAnalytics::InformationRatio(Ra, Rb, scale)
}

InformationRatio(managers[, 1:6])
```

returns

```
                            HAM1     HAM2    HAM3      HAM4      HAM5    HAM6
Information Ratio: zero 1.549119 1.373211 1.19553 0.6592017 0.2355561 1.66417
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? If it is, how do I report it? I couldn't get past [this page](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/returnanalytics/), no bugtracker whatsoever. I thought of writing an email, but I've seen developers here, so SO post is probably a good option, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Rb* is not supposed to be a scalar, it should be a time series.

*Rb* is described in the documentation as

```
Rb: return vector of the benchmark asset
```

So I suppose that documentation could be more clear, I'll look to improve that to specifiy a time series.  We need to merge the time series of benchmark returns to the time series of asset returns to do the calculation.

here is a working example with time series input for *Rb*:

```
data(managers)
rb<-xts( rep(0,nrow(managers)), order.by=index(managers) )
colnames(rb)<-'zero'
InformationRatio(managers,rb)
```

produces:

```
                            HAM1     HAM2    HAM3      HAM4      HAM5    HAM6 EDHEC LS EQ  SP500 TR US 10Y TR US 3m TR
Information Ratio: zero 1.549119 1.373211 1.19553 0.6592017 0.2355561 1.66417    1.665694 0.6448502 0.7265079 7.620057
```

As for **Return.excess**, I think it makes sense to not allow colnames collisions there, as you're trying to determine excess returns of one series to another series.  the code you pasted above is aimed at merging the series and creating an output series with the same index as the input series.  That operation could be done more efficiently now than it could when the function was originally written (before *xts*), and I'll take a look at that too.

Generally, bug reports for an **R** package should go to the package website or to the package maintainer.  email would have been fine.  **SO** should be for questions of usage, not bug reports, in general, as bugs get fixed, and **SO** remains with stale data.